# How do I define the density of system?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, statistical-thermodynamics, thermodynamics

Lets' say I have a solid nanomaterial made with *N* atoms in a simulation box with a volume of *V* as shown below. In this case, the number density of my material is simply $\frac{N}{Volume\; of \; occupied\;3D\; space}$.

[image: Solid Sphere]

but what if I have a nanomaterial with $N$ atoms in the same simulation box, but $N_{1}$ atoms are in the solid phase and $N_{2}$ atoms are in the gas phase $\left( N_{1} + N_{2} = N \right)$.

[image]

How should I calculate the number density of my material in this case? Do I consider the whole box volume $V$? do I have to find an average over the whole material?

Comment: To keep things from getting too long here, I moved the discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62241476#62241476)

Comment: Have you figured out the answer over the last 8 months? Please update us!